# How to save cropped image on key press event generated from Crop Box

Tags: image, key, crop

$("#btnCrpPhoto").on("click", function () {

```
    console.log("clickphoto");
    console.log($('#hfX').val());
    console.log($('#hfY').val());
    console.log($('#hfHeight').val());
    console.log($('#hfWidth').val());
```

}
insted of this i want to save on key press

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('#imageSize').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 65) {

}
you can use this function.